# Running google colab notebook on network gpu

Tags: localhost, google-colaboratory

I want to run a google colab notebook using a local gpu in my network.
I have 2 pcs - pc1 is trying to run the notebook, pc2 has the gpu.

The reason I want to use google colab is that sometimes the pc with the gpu (pc2) is busy and I want to switch quickly to google colab servers on pc1.

I managed to do two things up until now:

1. Run locally the notebook from colab on the pc with the gpu (pc2) using the command:
   jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' --port=8888 --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
   and then write in google colab:
   http://localhost:8888/?token=...
2. Run a jupyter notebook (not colab) from pc1 on pc2 (by adding flag --ip 0.0.0.0 when I start the server on pc2 and connecting to it from pc1).

The problem is that I can't write "http://pc2:8888/?token=..." on colab interface, it expects to get "localhost" instead of "pc2".

Is there a way to use tunneling or something similar to deal with it?

thanks